# In Python 2.7, how can i replace 't' with 'top' and 'h' with 'hop' only when 'th' is not visible

Tags: python, regex, replace

I am new here and python as well but i want to give it a try!
I would like to replace 't' with 'top' and 'h' with 'hop' in a sentence , only when 'th' is not visible because 'th' will become 'thop'. For example : 'Thi hi tea' has to become 'thopi hopi topea'.
I have this code:

```
sentence = str(raw_input('give me a sentence '))

start = 0
out = ''
while True:
    i = string.find( sentence, 'th', start )
    if i == -1:
        sentence = sentence.replace('t', 'top')
        sentence = sentence.replace('h', 'hop')
        break
    out = out + sentence[start:i] + 'thop'
    start = i+2
```

but is not working...Any ideas?

Comment: regular expressions is an idea. http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: You don't have to check to see whether something is in a string before replacing it. If the text you're replacing isn't in the string, `replace()` won't do anything, but it's not an error either. And even if you did want to do that, you'd do `string1 in string2` rather than using `find()`.

Comment: @user2343875: Rather than saying "it is not working", please provide exactly why it is not working. Is it giving you an error? Post the error. Are you giving it some input and the output is incorrect? Show us the input, and the incorrect output.

Answer (score 6):

```
import re

str = 'Thi hi tea'

re.sub(r'(?i)h|t(?!h)', r'\g<0>op', str)
```

yields

```
'Thopi hopi topea'
```

To break it down,

- `import re` imports the regular expression library from which we use the substitution, `sub`, function
- `(?i)` makes the regex case-insesitive
- `t(?!h)` matches a 't' not followed by an 'h'
- `\g<0>op` is a replacement string that substitutes the original text followed by `"op"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function:

```
>>>input : 'Thi hi tea'

>>>def function(string):
       string = string.lower()
       string = string.replace('t','top')   #replace all the 't' with 'top' from the string
       string = string.replace('h','hop')   # replace all the 'h' with 'hop'
       string =  string.replace('tophop','thop')   #where t and h will be together there i will get 'tophop', so i am replacing 'tophop' with 'thop'
       return string.capitalize() #for capitalize the first letter
```

answer:----------

```
>>>function('Thi hi tea')
'Thopi hopi topea'

>>>function('Hi,who is there?')
'Hopi,whopo is thopere?'
```

Thanks